# How to convert Streamreader data to XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, streamreader

In C#, I am trying to get call a webservice which returns an XML file.

I can make a HttpWebRequest to the webservice and store the output in a StreamReader. But how can I convert this data into an XMLDocument?

Comment: Is this a SOAP-based web service? Then you should not be using HttpWebRequest. Just use "Add Service Reference" and call the "methods" of the proxy class that is created for you - no XML involved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`XmlDocument.Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load.aspx) - I'm using the overload that accepts an `XmlReader` to cash in on [`XmlReader.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756wd7zs.aspx)'s auto-encoding detection:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
using(Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()) {        
    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream)) {
        document.Load(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: That assumes that the response stream encoding is the same as the XML encoding.  It doesn't have to be.

Comment: I note that whilst you are creating an XmlReader, you're still only passing the original 'stream' object into document.Load()

Answer (score 2):

Use System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(streamreader);

Answer (score 0):

You should store the received output in a StringWriter or just a stringand the load it using XmlDocument.Load(string).

Comment: Because he wants to store it :). Actually i would go for Jeff's solution above.